# Email to rows in html table populated with data from mysql database via while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I have an HTML table populated with data from a MySQL database using a `while()` loop. This database has the following structure:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++
| id | name | email |
+++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to make is so the user can send e-mails to a selected group of users (rows), and I'm considering one of the following solutions:

1. A button for each row that says 'Send invitation email' or
2. Checkboxes to select those I want to send invitation email and a 'Submit' button that submits the form.

I'm not sure how to get the data into the form to be processed.

Comment: Can we assume that you know how to send a email using php?

Comment: Please consider marking on of the below answers as accepted. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a form that submits to a PHP sound surrounding your `<table>.`
In each row, have a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" />
```

And a submit button (inside the form) at the bottom. On the PHP page:

```
<?php
$emails = $_POST['emails'];
foreach ($emails as $email) {
   ###Logic to send your HTML e-mail
}
?>
```

Comment: It should be `type="checkbox" name="emails[]"`. The brackets go with the name, not the type.

Comment: Thanks David and Barmar. I got it to work with Davids code examples with a few alterations; move the [] from type to name, and only have {$row['email']} in value. Thanks for the help - you guys rock :)

Comment: Wow that was embarrassing. Many apologies!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make the PHP assign an unique ID and a value to each checkbox, to know which checkboxes are selected and the email address. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="5" value="email@foo.com">email@foo.com
```

Also, use an `<input type="hidden">` to store the total number of checkboxes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="totalCheckboxes" value="20">
```

On the target page (the one specified in `<form action="...">`), get the total number of checkboxes from the hidden `<input>`, and in a For cycle:

- Read and store the email of each checkbox;
- Send the e-mail to the stored address.

The final code should look like this:

**Form page**

```
<form method="POST" action="target.php">
<table><tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="1" value="foo@bar.com"></td>
    <td>foo@bar.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="2" value="herp@derp.com"></td>
    <td>herp@derp.com</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="hidden" name="totalCheckboxes" value="2">
</form>
```

**Target page**

```
<?php
$total=$_POST['totalCheckboxes'];
for ($k=1; $k!=$total; $k++) {
   if ($_POST[$k]) {
      // Email
   }
}
?>
```